# Threadpool queue stalling on 10th item

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker, threadpool

I'm having a problem with my test application.  I'm running a win form application which can post requests to a web service.  There is a timer which periodically adds items to the queue of requests.  I have a class called AutoManager which is used to pick items off the queue and send them off to the web service.

In TryKickQueue() it adds an IAutoProcessor onto the threadpool queue.  Once the IAutoProcessor is finished it calls back to the AutoManager to remove itself from the queue.

This works fine and runs the first 10 requests no problem however for some reason I can't figure out the 10th thread never finishes and so it gets stuck.  It's weird because it is always the 10th.  Am I doing something wrong, should I be cleaning things up?

Should this happen or is it probably a deadlock that i've not been able to find?

Many thanks
Neil

```
    public AutoManager(Settings _settings, Log _log)
    {
        m_sessionKicker = new BackgroundWorker();
        m_sessionKicker.DoWork += SessionKickerDoWork;
        m_sessionKicker.RunWorkerCompleted += SessionKickerRunCompleted;
        m_sessionKicker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        m_sessionKicker.RunWorkerAsync();

        m_processorQueue = new List<IAutoProcessor>();
        m_inProcessingQueue = new List<IAutoProcessor>();
    }

    private void SessionKickerDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        bool bFinished = false;

        while (!bFinished)
        {
            TryKickQueue();
        }
    }

    private void TryKickQueue()
    {
        object thisObject = new Object();

        lock (thisObject)
        {
            if (m_processorQueue.Count > 0 && m_inProcessingQueue.Count < m_settings.MaxThreads)
            {
                IAutoProcessor proc = m_processorQueue[0];
                m_inProcessingQueue.Add(proc);
                m_processorQueue.RemoveAt(0);

                if (proc != null)
                {
                    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(proc.SendData));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnRemoveAutoProcessor(IAutoProcessor _autoProcessor)
    {
        object thisObject = new Object();

        lock (thisObject)
        {
            m_inProcessingQueue.Remove(_autoProcessor);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lock around the use of m_processorQueue is invalid. You're locking om the local variable thisObject but that means each thread has its own lock-object and they will never wait...

Declare `thisObject` so that it has the same scope and lifetime as `m_processorQueue`.

But I also note that your bgw does a busy loop, it will consume a lot of CPU time. You need some mechanism to wait on an empty queue.

If you are using Fx4 then use the  ConcurrentQueue. Otherwise look for a good implementation of a queue.

Comment: Couldn't you directly lock on m_processorQueue?

Comment: Thanks, declaring the locks fixed some problems.  Also adding a sleep to the busy loop fixed the rest of the problems as the application was stalling because the loop had it constantly locked.

For now that should be enough but once I get to upgrade to .net4.0 I'll be able to use the proper concurrent libraries.

Thanks for the quick response.
Neil

Comment: @Mario: In practice, yes. But it is considered a 'best practice' to use a separate object, just in case other code (the queue itself) locks on it. Better to have full and sole control over the locker.

Answer (score 0):

Move your lock (thisObject) from local to method from global to type.

```
    static object thisObject = new Object();
    private void TryKickQueue() 
    { 
        lock (thisObject) 
        { 
           // your logic
        } 
    } 

    public void OnRemoveAutoProcessor(IAutoProcessor _autoProcessor) 
    { 
        lock (thisObject) 
        { 
           //your logic
        } 
    }
```

Not sure why you are checking this `m_inProcessingQueue.Count < m_settings.MaxThreads`.

Comment: why make it static?  The queue isn't.

Comment: In this case, OnRemoveAutoProcessor(IAutoProcessor _autoProcessor) is a public method.